# Electrostatics- Attraction between a negatively charged balloon and a plastic bottle

Tags: electrostatics, home-experiment

Let's say there is a negatively charged balloon. There is also a neutrally charged plastic bottle. You know that since the plastic bottle is an insulator, polarization occurs. Is it true that since the positive protons in the plastic bottle get closer so it gets attracted towards the balloon?

Answer (score 1):

No. Polarization of charges only occurs in conductors. to charge and insulator you need to rub to bodies .a.k.a charging by friction. it is true that atoms of plastics bottle will remain fix but there will a very little change of arrangement of nucleus and electrons. this rearrangement will happen when the atoms of plastic bottle are remain fixed

Comment: Polarisation occurs only in conductors? Heard of dielectrics ? @Bhavay Luthra

Comment: i never said that polarization don't  happen in insulator, it happens but without movement of atoms

Comment: @AdityaGarg please correct me if it explanation seems wrong